# How do I fix improper EOF in git / vagrant?

Tags: git, vagrant

I have a file that runs properly on my linux machine and when I pull the repo onto my windows machine the file is intact and correct.

However, when I boot my vagrant server, which has a virtual drive to my windows machine, I get a javascript error in the browser like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

When I inspect the file, the last few lines are gone and I see:

```
????????????????????????
```

at the end of the file.

I have already gone over the 'autocrlf' instructions from github (https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) and it had zero effect.

I'm not actually sure what's happening... but how do I fix it?

Comment: And if you set autocrlf to false, and make sure there is no .gitattributes with eol directove in them, ie if you make sure there is *no* automatic conversion done by git, do you still see that issue? If yes, this isn't related to eol.

Comment: Try NOT to place git repositories on `vboxsf` - default synced folder option. It has known issue with git (lack sym / hard links support).

Comment: @VonC - tried that too. No dice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .gitattributes file with a rule converting text files (which are automatically detected) from CRLF (`\r\n`) to LF (`\n`) on git checkout.

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

You'll need to do a git checkout for these changes to take effect.

```
git add . -u
git commit -m "Saving files before refreshing line endings"

git rm --cached -r .

git reset --hard

git add .
# It is perfectly safe to see a lot of messages here that read
# "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file."

git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
```

That's it – your CRLF EOL characters are converted to LF (and will stay that way). Let me know if you have any questions!